# Perform special functions with drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html

I've been sitting on a certain function for quite some time now. After a lot of research and testing, I have not come up with a final solution.
solution. The user should be able to select which table row he wants to edit with the help of a dropdown menu. Based on the dropdown selection
after confirming a button, input fields should appear in the corresponding row, so that the user can correct erroneous data manually.
manually in case of erroneous data. However, the input should only overwrite the respective cell if something has been typed there (input field).
My table always consists of 10 rows, thus 10 dropdown selection options.

***How the buttons work:***

edit = make the fields appear after dropdown selection

confirm = make fields disappear again and overwrite what has been written in the fields in the respective cells but only if something has been typed there

How I manually insert input fields in the respective table cells
I already know and have implemented in this way:

```js
<script>
function createInputFields() {
  var row1 = document.getElementById("tableLKW").rows[1].cells;
  var row2 = document.getElementById("tableLKW").rows[2].cells;
  
  row1[0].innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='newInputBoxRow1'>";
  row1[1].innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='newInputBoxRow1'>";
  row2[0].innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='newInputBoxRow2'>";
}
</script>

<button onclick="createInputFields()"></button>
```

My table (embellished with bootstrap) and dropdown selection looks like this.

***Table:***

```html
<table id="tabelleLKW" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-dark">
    <thead class="thead-light"> 
        <tr>
            <th style scope="col"><p align="center">position</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">number</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">driver's name</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">vehicle identification</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">status</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">phone</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">short code</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">gate</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">empties</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">track</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">priority</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">from</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">to</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td><p align="center">1</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Number</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Name</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder vehicle identification</td>
        <td>placeholder status</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder number</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder code</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>placeholder empties</td>
        <td>placeholder track</td>
        <td>placeholder priority</td>
        <td>placeholder from</td>
        <td>placeholder to</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p align="center">2</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Number</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Name</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder vehicle identification</td>
        <td>placeholder status</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder number</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder code</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>placeholder empties</td>
        <td>placeholder track</td>
        <td>placeholder priority</td>
        <td>placeholder from</td>
        <td>placeholder to</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p align="center">3</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Number</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Name</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder vehicle identification</td>
        <td>placeholder status</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder number</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder code</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>placeholder empties</td>
        <td>placeholder track</td>
        <td>placeholder priority</td>
        <td>placeholder from</td>
        <td>placeholder to</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p align="center">4</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Number</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Name</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder vehicle identification</td>
        <td>placeholder status</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder number</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder code</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>placeholder empties</td>
        <td>placeholder track</td>
        <td>placeholder priority</td>
        <td>placeholder from</td>
        <td>placeholder to</td>
      </tr>
    .. etc
```

***Dropdown:***

```html
<label for="table-rows">Choose a table row:</label>
<select name="table-rows" id="table-row">
    <option value="row1" id="choice1">Table Row 1</option>
    <option value="row2" id="choice2">Table Row 2</option>
    <option value="row3" id="choice3">Table Row 3</option>
    <option value="row4" id="choice4">Table Row 4</option>
</select>
```

I know that one implements this with the if/else query, only I don't know exactly how to combine the selection from the dropdown with the confirmation button and the if
else query. Surely one connects the if/else query with the ID's of the respective options of the dropdowns.

Some screenshots (visualizations) of how this should look like.

***before the selection:***
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHWsD.png)

***after the selection:***
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIDh5.png)

Unfortunately I am still a beginner in Javascript and HTML and hope that you can help me. I hope that I have described and shown everything well and I apologize in advance for my not so clean English. **Thank you!**

Comment: 1. I'd place edit buttons inside each row instead of a cumbersome dropdown (or just make the row clickable) 2. I'd put the current cell content inside the input, this way you see what you're editing and you don't have to check for empty fields when saving

Comment: Can you please clarify how you're hydrating the data inside the tables? Is it through an API call or is it rendered from the server? Like you're using PHP or some other language/framework to render the table data. This could change the answer, so I would like to be sure.

Comment: Here's the start of a system I'd use for this: https://jsfiddle.net/dfsu41c9/

Comment: @AseemLalfakawma I am using HTML for the basic table framework, and CSS for some buttons, but they are not visible in the version (not relevant to the question). Also PHP is included there for the current time/date display and javascript for timer functions (also not in this version). I embellished the table with the Twitter Bootstrap. I inserted the data in the table manually for now, as you can see in the code snippets at the top of the table. At a later stage, this should happen via a database, but only when everything is really functions/layout etc. and works. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ChrisG I think the dropdown menu thing is a bit too much and complex to understand. I would like to implement it that way with jsfiddle. I just had a look at this. How exactly does it overwrite the data and how exactly can I make the field disappear again. Somehow I get stuck after pressing once on a record and then somehow can't get away from there.

Comment: Yes, like I said, this is how I'd *start* implementing this. Study my code to understand the main approach: user input changes app state / updates data -> HTML is updated to reflect new state. I didn't implement a way to save the changes yet.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks first of all for your answer. I will take my time to look at your code and look up anything not understandable so I can understand your code. This is my first contact with jsfiddle ever. Sorry if I was too hasty with the save function. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Dropdown and button

```
<label for="table-rows">Choose a table row:</label>
<select name="table-rows" id="table-row">
    <option value="row1" id="choice1">Table Row 1</option>
</select>
<button>Edit</button>
```

```js
// js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const dropdown = document.querySelector('[name="table-rows"]');

// This will come to use later, you need to store the data as
// we're directly changing the HTML and you can restore it incase
// the user cancels the 'Edit'
let storedEditData = [];

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // We add +1 to the selectedIndex here because we don't want 0th index
    // 0th index is the header field
    const tableRow = document.querySelector('#tabelleLKW').rows[dropdown.selectedIndex + 1];
    
    // Now you loop through all the cells from the row that
    // was selected and add an input element in it.
    for (let i = 0; i < tableRow.cells.length; ++i) {
      const item = tableRow.cells.item(i);
      
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('class', 'your-input-class');
      // Data attribute to store the row and cell id for later
      // reference. For getting input, etc.
      input.setAttribute('data-cell-id', `row-${dropdown.selectedIndex + 1}-cell-${i}`);
      input.value = item.innerText;

      // Save data
      storedEditData = tableRow.cells;
      
      item.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the HTML
      item.appendChild(input); // Append the new input
      
      // further code ...
    }
});
```

I've added a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/alalfakawma-the-styleful/pen/mdxEXEb). Hope you can use this as an example and go forward from here.

Comment: Wow! Thank you Aseem Lalfakawma for your reply. Exactly like in your CodePen example I wanted to have it and it works like that. I created a new empty project to implement it but somehow it doesn't work. Of course I added the missing tags that CodePen takes. It only works in your CodePen example. I added the javaScript script to the head tag.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're placing your HTML code, there may be other HTML in that page other that the above and it's taking the wrong element, you can check what is being selected, see `querySelector` parts, maybe it's the `button` selector, as i'm selecting a generic button element. You could change it to suit your needs. Also, check if you have errors in your console. Also, move your script at the end of the `body` tag, could be the cause. Or just add `defer` attribute to the script tag.

Comment: I have now moved the script near the end of the body tag and now it works. I think that was the cause. Thank you! Now I will first continue to see how I can maintain and save the written in the table cells as well as the disappear.

Comment: Great. Happy to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm completely following what your problem is but is it that you are not sure how to run a function on option select? Here's a simple example if so:

```
<select id="osDemo" onchange="detectChange(this)">
    <option value="Linux">Linux</option>
    <option value="Windows">Windows</option>
    <option value="MacOS">MacOS</option>
</select>
```

notice the 'onchange' attribute and 'detectChange()' function.

If that is not correct please let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: My original idea was to use a dropdown menu to select the row you want to edit. This would be confirmed with an edit button. Then the input fields appear. After the input you would then confirm the input and it is then only overwritten where the user has typed something, so that everything else still remains. I think that the whole functionality is not well thought out and also not user friendly or too cumbersome.